# Shopify API orders/create webhook access issue

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am new to shopify app development so please do not roast me for asking this basic question.
I am creating an app that will charge customers based on the total conversion value of the sales that the app helps the merchant make.
In order to do this I need to access the order information as soon as the a sale is made on the store.
After checking the shopify webhook documentation says that I will need the "Orders" and "Marketplace Orders" access scopes to get orders information that I need. It turns out the I also need an additional permission from shopify to be able to add those scopes in my app. I did make a request from my shopify app dashboard to allow my app to use these access scopes but it got rejected.
Shopify is asking me to provide the reasons why my app needs to access the orders that are older than 60. But my app doesn't need to access orders that are older than 60 days I just need to get the orders that have a specific discount code applied(which is created by my app).

So here are my questions:

Do I really need to access orders older than 60 days to achieve this?
Is there any other way for me to access just the orders that are created in the duration the app was installed on a merchant's store?
Shopify's response to my request suggests that there are other methods of accessing orders within the 60 day window?

I requested shopify to allow my app to use the "Orders" and "Marketplace Orders" access scopes but it got rejected
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58wFR.png)

Comment: Are you submit the app with request to orders that are 60 days older?

Comment: @Onkar There is no option to request access to orders less than 60 days old

Comment: By default when you add `read_orders` & `write_orders ` it allow less than 60 days orders, if you need more than 60 days than made a request from app backend.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/0gbima_ow4Z5

Comment: @Onkar read_orders scope is all I needed. Thanks for the help man.